# Multiple events handler for any item on listview row (android)?

Tags: android, event-handling, android-listview

How can I handler multiple event of any items on a simple row on a listView?
example: each row on my listview got 2 button one for view and another for editing.

when I just put a method name on the onclick atribute on my xml and got this error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a method methodName in the 
activity class android.app.Application for onClick handler on view class 
android.widget.ImageButton
```

my list row

```
<TextView 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/timeOrder"/>

<TextView 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/phoneNumberOrden"/>

<TextView 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/nameOrder"/>

<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageButton 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_view"
        android:contentDescription="@string/contentDescription"
        android:onClick="details"
        />

    <ImageButton 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_call"
        android:contentDescription="@string/contentDescription"
        android:onClick="call"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: What does your `onClick` method look like?

Comment: like this public void call(View vew){}

Comment: Please show some code so that it would be easy for other to find the issue and provide a solution for it.

Comment: you should try registering both of your buttons with onClickListener() inside you Adapter's getView() method .